# SeekBar preference change volume

Tags: android, media-player, volume, seekbar, preference

I have a SeekBarPreference and i would like to handle with it the volume of the application. I created the SeekBarPreference in xml but I do not really know what I should write in java class to configure it .

Please help me to configure the SeekBarPreference to control the volume of the application.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import android.app.Activity;

import android.content.Context;

import android.media.AudioManager;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.widget.SeekBar;

import android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    private SeekBar volumeSeekbar = null;
    private AudioManager audioManager = null; 

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        initControls();
    }

    private void initControls()
    {
        try
        {
            volumeSeekbar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
            audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
            volumeSeekbar.setMax(audioManager
                    .getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));
            volumeSeekbar.setProgress(audioManager
                    .getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));   


            volumeSeekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() 
            {
                @Override
                public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) 
                {
                }

                @Override
                public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) 
                {
                }

                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int progress, boolean arg2) 
                {
                    audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                            progress, 0);
                }
            });
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```